# Windows 10 - Time Screen Limit does not work

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem regarding limiting the screen time in Windows 10. I try to set up this limits using the CMD by typing the following command: `net user <username> /times:sun,18:00-21:00`. Even though the time limit is set up, I am still able to login into my user account. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
net user <username> /time:<day>,<time>
```

The correct syntax of the command is this.

You used '`times`' instead of `'time'` in yours, that could be the reason it doesn't work.

Also,
The short form of the days are these:

Su  - Sunday
M   - Monday
T   - Tuesday
W   - Wednesday
Th  - Thursday
F   - Friday
Sa  - Saturday

(as you used '`sun`' it did not work)

---

So, in conclution, your command would be something like `net user <username> /time:su,18:00-21:00`

Comment: instead of `su` I use `so` (Sonntag) because the language of my system is German. When I type `net user <username>` I can see at "Allowed Login Times" the limit I've set up. But it still does not work, because I can login outside these allowed times. And both `time` and `times` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To set the time-limit for another user, you must run CMD as Administrator.

Running as administrator is required for it to work.